# create polymial in powers of (x-1) from given coefficients in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, polynomials

I have the following coefficient matrix.

```
import numpy as np
coeffMatrix = np.array([[  1.        ,   1.46599761,   0.        ,   0.25228421],
   [  2.71828183,   2.22285026,   0.75685264,   1.69107137],
   [  7.3890561 ,   8.80976965,   5.83006675,  -1.94335558],
   [ 20.08553692,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ]])
```

I can then create a polynomials `s0` as follows:

```
s0 = np.poly1d(coeffMatrix[0][::-1])
print (s0)
```

It prints out the following output:

```
        3
0.2523 x + 1.466 x + 1
```

I now want to create `s1` using `coeffMatrix[1][::-1]` as the coefficients but I want `s1` to be in powers of (x-1).

How can I do this?

On a side note. I don't know how to copy paste jupyter notebook input output straight into stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `variable` parameter. I used http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html

(I prefer to look on `np.array` as matrix and not as list of arrays)

```
s1 = np.poly1d(coeffMatrix[1, ::-1], variable='(x-1)')
print(s1)
```